# Why does localhost:5000 not work in Flask Python?

Tags: python, flask

I'm using flask app factory pattern like and have this `helloworld.py` file

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'This is the home page'


if __name__=="__name__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Then I run the app in Terminal :

```
python helloworld.py
```

> (venv) C:\Users\Jayalakshmi.S1\myproject>python helloworld.py
>
> (venv) C:\Users\Jayalakshmi.S1\myproject>

But when I go to `http://localhost:5000` it doesn't work. It says:

> Can’t reach this page
>
> Make sure the web address http://127.0.0.1:5000 is correct

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you wrote `if __name__=="__name__":` instead of `if __name__=="__main__":`.

Since that will never be true, your `app.run` never happens. That's why when you run the script, it just returns immediately, instead of printing out something like `* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/` and then waiting.

You *also* almost always want to run Flask this way:

```
set FLASK_APP=helloworld.py
flask run
```

… instead of:

```
python helloworld.py
```

Comment: Thank you...Thank you so much

Comment: Shouldn't this be `export` instead of `set`?!

Comment: @Cleb On Windows?

Comment: @Cleb Well, that's actually bash, not Unix… but close enough; most people on Unix systems (with a terminal) are either using bash, or know what they're doing (and anyone using bash on Windows knows what they're doing). But anyway, the OP is clearly on Windows, given the `C:\Users\Jayalakshmi.S1\myproject>`, so it shouldn't be `export`.

Answer (score 1):

Your if condition is wrong. You should mention the main module which you're running...

```
if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```